# Magento 2.3.3 Class argument is invalid issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, php-7.3

I have "mass change attribute set" extension with Magento 2.3.3. All works with Magento 2.3.2 but now is issue with magento 2.3.3. How i can fix this error?

> Class argument is invalid:
>   developer_name\ChangeAttributeSet\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="changeattributeset">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">changeattributeset</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change attribute set</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">developer_name\ChangeAttributeSet\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options</argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">changeattributeset/product/massChangeattributeset</item>
                    <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">changeattributeset</item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change attribute set</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to assign selected products to new attribute set?</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>             
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

update your xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="changeattributeset">
            <settings>
                <type>changeattributeset</type>
                <label translate="true">Change attribute set</label>
                <actions class="developer_name\ChangeAttributeSet\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options"/>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

Then in di.xml

> developer_name\ChangeAttributeSet\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="developer_name\ChangeAttributeSet\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">changeattributeset/product/massChangeattributeset</item>
                <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">changeattributeset</item>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Change attribute set</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Are you sure to assign selected products to new attribute set?</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class in the configurableObject needs to extend \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider in order to be valid.

Kind regards,